# Clickhouse running diff with grouping

Tags: clickhouse

### General Task

A table consists of three columns (*time*, *key*, *value*). The task is to calculate a running difference for each key.
So, from input

```
---------------
| time | key | value |
---------------
| 1    | A   | 4     |
| 2    | B   | 1     |
| 3    | A   | 6     |
| 4    | A   | 7     |
| 5    | B   | 3     |
| 6    | B   | 7     |
```

it is desired to get

```
----------------------
| key | value | delta |
----------------------
| A   | 4     |  0    |
| B   | 1     |  0    |
| A   | 6     |  2    |
| A   | 7     |  1    |
| B   | 3     |  2    |
| B   | 7     |  4    |
```

### Approaches

1. `runningDifference` function. Works, if the key is fixed. So we can

   ```
   select *, runningDifference(value) from
       (SELECT key, value from table where key = 'A' order by time)
   ```

   Note that subquery *is* necessary here. This solution suffers when you want to get this for different *key*s
2. `groupArray`.

   ```
   select key, groupArray(value) from
       (SELECT key, value from table order by time)
       group by key
   ```

   So, now we get a key and an array of elements with this key. Good.

   But **how to calculate a sliding difference**? If we could do that, then `ARRAY JOIN` would lead us to a result.

   Or we can even `zip` the array with itself and then apply lambda (we have `arrayMap` for that) but... we don't have any `zip` alternative.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Solution with arrays:

```sql
WITH 
   groupArray(value) as time_sorted_vals,
   arrayEnumerate(time_sorted_vals) as indexes,
   arrayMap( i -> time_sorted_vals[i] - time_sorted_vals[i-1], indexes) as running_diffs
SELECT 
   key,
   running_diffs
FROM 
    (SELECT key, value from table order by time)
GROUP by key
```

Other option (doing sort inside each group separately, which is more optimal in a lot of cases)

```sql
WITH
   groupArray( tuple(value,time) ) as val_time_tuples,
   arraySort( x -> x.2, val_time_tuples ) as val_time_tuples_sorted,
   arrayMap( t -> t.1, indexes) as time_sorted_vals,
   arrayEnumerate(time_sorted_vals) as indexes,
   arrayMap( i -> time_sorted_vals[i] - time_sorted_vals[i-1], indexes) as running_diffs
SELECT 
   key,
   running_diffs
FROM 
   time
GROUP by key
```

and you can apply ARRAY JOIN on the result afterward.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering how would the query look like if in the result we also wanted to include `time` column, meaning: `| time | key | value | delta |`?

Comment: This answer was posted years ago, for today Sep 29th, 2021, we can use `arrayDifference` instead of `arrayMap`. And we can `ARRAY JOIN` so that we can get a tabulated result instead of a nested array. That is:

Comment: see my posted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This question was posted years ago, for today, Sep 29th, 2021, we can use `arrayDifference` instead of `arrayMap`. And we can `ARRAY JOIN` so that we can get a tabulated result instead of a nested array.

```
SELECT key, sorted_time, time_sorted_vals, running_diffs
FROM (
WITH
   groupArray( tuple(value,time) ) as val_time_tuples,
   arraySort( x -> x.2, val_time_tuples ) as val_time_tuples_sorted,
   arrayMap( t -> t.1, val_time_tuples_sorted) as time_sorted_vals,
   arrayMap( t -> t.2, val_time_tuples_sorted) as sorted_time,
   arrayDifference(time_sorted_vals) as running_diffs
SELECT 
   key,
   sorted_time,
   time_sorted_vals,
   running_diffs
FROM 
   table_name
GROUP by key)
ARRAY JOIN sorted_time, time_sorted_vals, running_diffs
```

The only restriction is that the `value` column should not be of nullable types.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've also encountered the problem and Clickhouse offers function `arrayDifference`.

```
WITH 
   groupArray(value) as vals
   arrayDifference(vals) as running_diffs
SELECT 
   key,
   running_diffs
FROM 
    (SELECT key, value from table order by time)
GROUP by key
```

Comment: Hello, yeah it's been a long time since the question was asked. Let me point that your answer doesn't solve the original question: your query prodice an array of diffs per each key, while it is desired to get the overall order persisited, a simple array join would not give you such a result.